# Applying a weighting function to a curve over a definite integral

Tags: normalization, integral, weighted-data, numerical-integration

I am trying to replicate a sensor's output by modeling the spectral signal it receives and *weighting that curve by the sensor's non-uniform spectral response curve.*

[Here are what the two spectral curves look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qItsO.png)

[image]

The red curve is my modeled signal. The black curve is the instrument response curve. **In layman's terms, I need to weight the red curve for each *v* based on the black curve.**

The goal of which is a comparison between weighted and unweighted curves.

I've tried a few methods (see a couple below) but am having trouble applying the sensor response function to my modeled spectral curve. L(*v*) is the signal curve and w(*v*) is the weighting function:

**Method 1**

$$
\frac{\int L(v)w(v) \, dv}{\int w(v) \, dv}
$$

This is initially what my advisor did - but this is just a weighted average (so it remains spectral).

---

**Method 2**

$$
\int \frac{ L(v)w(v)}{\overline x}
$$

where $$\overline x \text{= average spectral response over the waveband.}$$

[But this gives different curves depending on the size of the waveband:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Zk5.png)

[image]

In my mind, the weighted curve should stay the same as I expand the waveband beyond the what the sensor responds to - since those wavelengths do not contribute to the signal.

---

This seems so simple to me in theory, but I can't seem to figure it out. Am I ignoring something obvious?

Comment: "Just a weighted average" is exactly what you need (except you shouldn't need to divide by anything: get rid of the denominator).  What do you mean by "remains spectral" and what is the matter with that?

Comment: @whuber - This is question is quite some time ago, but why do you say "weighted average"? Isn't the division, i.e. presence of the denominator, responsible for the averaging? How would weighting using an integral work?

Comment: @stars83clouds The function $w$ is the unnormalized weight. The weighted average of a function $f$ then is (by definition) $\int f(x)w(x)\,\mathrm{d}x / \int w(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$

Comment: But you suggested that he remove the denominator....does that mean he didn't exactly need a weighted average? Without the denominator, what is the expression called? A weighted integral?

Comment: @stars83clouds When we call something like $w$ a "weighting function" for the purposes of averaging, it is understood it sums (or integrates) to unity.  This is allowable because $w$ can always be replaced by $w/\int w(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ without changing the *relative* weights.  Doing this (greatly) clarifies the question because it means factors of $1/\int w(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ need not explicitly appear.